# Use rel="canonical" on structurally same pages?

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I have a Q/A site provided in 2 languages: English or German. On the site there's overview pages for tags used for questions. Now, depending on the language set for the site, such overview page URL will look like this:

**mysite.com/tag/mathematics** (English)

or this:

**mysite.com/tag/mathematik** (German)

Also, the first one will present questions asked in English, the second - in German.

My question is: is this kind of structure considered the same/duplicated content by Google? To wrap this up:

- the overview pages look the same
- UI is displayed in English or German
- the "real" content (questions) is different for each language

Do I need to use `rel="canonical"` in `<head>` in this case to tell Google which URL I prefer to be indexed?

Answer (score 1):

Content in different languages is not considered duplicate.

See here [Does translated content cause a duplicate content issue?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=UDg2AGRGjLQ)

and this link should be helpful too : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, that''s helpful. In the end, even if it's not considered duplicated content, I put the `rel="canonical"` on the pages anyway, so Google bots know which URL is the preferred one. In my case - English.

Comment: No, dont use canonical here. Look into hreflang : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: +1 for hreflang! It's designed exactly for situations like this, it should be the ideal choice (with or without rel-canonical). Since a few months ago hreflang self-references are also a canonicalisation factor, so rel-canonical should be less of a concern, too. And yes, we (Google) have no dup-content penalty, in fact never had.